# Implicit vs. Explicit Default Constructor Call

Tags: c++, default-constructor

Assuming my knowledge of both the below methods for creating an object calling the default constructor(provided by the compiler) is true.

```
class A
{
    int a,b;
    //No programmer defined constructor
}
...
A o1; //Implicit Call I believe
A o2 = A(); //Explicit Call
```

Why does `A o2 = A();` causes the members(a,b) of object `o2` to initialize itself with default values(0) but not `A o;`(they are initialized with garbage values) ? Is it undefined behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quotes are from Standard p8.5/1

There is no user-defined constructor here, so, compiler will use the default one. And default constructor will not initialize members with zeros.

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
> default-initialized.
>
> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), constructors
> are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3),
> and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload
> resolution (13.3). The constructor thus selected is called, with an
> empty argument list, to initialize the object.

In second case will be value-initialization.

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (),
> shall be value-initialized.
>
> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided
> or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized
> and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked,
> and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is
> default-initialized;
>
> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each
> non-static data member and each base-class subobject is
> zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;

Answer (score -2):

In both the cases default constructor provided by compiler will be called. Most likely c++ compiler initializes value to some garbage value. c++ compiler will not initialize the value to 0 in case of default constructor being called, unless already the memory is dumped with zeros. I tried this scenario , I did not see any difference in the value assigned for a and b in both the objects.

Comment: It is wrong, look at standard rules of initialization.